int8 post-training-quantization for model with complex input in TensorFlow
I would like to profit from post-training-quantization to 8 bit when converting a keras model to a tflite model. In most cases, this can be performed as such:
import tensorflow as tf

def data_gen():
    for data in dataset_dict:
        # scaling process ...
        yield data

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
q_model = converter.convert()

However, if a model is trained on np.complex128 or np.complex64 data of arbitrary shape, I can't apply astype() in a meaningful way. Even if $Re$ and $Im$ were cast as int8 separately and combined back, they would still be of type complex128. The model is saved and can't be retrained easily. Are there any options to achieve the quantization?
